# Why sed s acting differently on RedHat vs Mobaxterm using regexp?

Tags: linux, sed, replace

I have a .txt file which includes "junk" characters, emojis.

Example:

```
12/11/2015, 12:07 - 5465464: Super Wakkka
12/11/2015, 12:30 - 89415: qwertz svima, nadam se 
12/11/2015, 12:34 - 55698742: Super nowsfd. 
12/11/2015, 17:19 - nbhgzerte: ich bin Suprs 
12/11/2015, 17:27 - 998877:
```

If I run following command on Mobaxterm:

```
sed 's/[^ -~]//g' my_file > output_file
```

everything is OK and emojis are removed.

But if I run the same on RHEL it deletes actually all characters besides colon, slash, minus, dot etc. 
Example of output:

```
//, : - :
//, : - :  ,
//, : - :  .
//, : - :
//, : - :
```

Can please anyone explain why it is working/not working as expected? I know I can change encoding on RHEL and than remove characters etc, but I really want to understand why is this command working as expected on Mobaxterm (CYGWIN_NT-10.0-WOW) and not on RHEL.

Thanks.

Comment: Presumably because the range of characters `[^ -~]` not between space and tilde is dependent on the locale's collation order?

Comment: @steeldriver can you explain a bit more? On the RHEL locale is set to "en_US.UTF-8". But I changed it to the same that is on my PC (de_DE.utf8) and I still got the same result. On my I use Mobaxterm and charset is set to "UTF-8 (Unicode)"

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "on MobaXterm" versus "on RHEL"? are you logging into the same server via MobaXterm client and also via a command line ssh client from a RHEL system? or to a RHEL server locally versus via MobaXterm?

Comment: @steeldriver - when I say RHEL, I mean I connect via putty to RHEL server. When I say Mobaxterm, I mean using Mobaxterm (Cygwin) on my local PC, which is running on Windows 10 and doing things locally on my PC.